Last Conversation between Moshe and Joshua
What is the source for this story?
Joshua is the last person to see Moses.  Moses asks Joshua if he has any last questions.  Joshua says :no, you've taught me everything and earned your eternity" and walks away.  He turns and says "wait -- I have one more question..."  But Moses was already gone.
I can't remember (or find) where this was from.
Bonus help?  Anyone know what the question was?

See Temura 16a.
